# Rails server side validations Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have multiple forms with different (number of) fields for a single model and database table. How do I add model validations?

I defined all validations in model, and when I tried to submit a form, Rails validates with each model field validation. Please tell me how to validate different forms with different fields with the same model in rails.

Answer (score 2):

Extract validations from the model into view-specific FormObjects. This way each form will use its own form object with only the validations it needs.

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects

https://medium.com/selleo/essential-rubyonrails-patterns-form-objects-b199aada6ec9

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to define validations in models, but issue came with making them FAT. More number of fields to validate will increase the number of lines in models. So, to do all this at one place without making models FAT and should get access to Active Record Validation. So, this can be achieved using active_interaction gem.

https://github.com/AaronLasseigne/active_interaction

https://taylor.fausak.me/2014/01/23/confidently-manage-business-logic-with-active-interaction/

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 forms with 10 fields and 20 fields respectively. (You can have multiple forms also.).

Add `form_type` attr_accessor & `hidden_field` in both forms with values `form1` & `form2`.

For Form-1 (10 fields), set object attribute `form_type` to `form1` & in validation you can skip validation using `form_type` like,

```
validates :name, presence: true, if: Proc { |obj| obj.form_type != 'form1' }
```

So it will check above validation only for Form-2 (where form_type is set to form2)

Comment: no need to add in table, you can set as `attr_accessor` in modal

Comment: You can also define a helper method `def form1?() form_type == 'form1' end` and do `, unless: :form1?`. Just a thought on increasing readability.

Comment: @Tom Yes and it can be implemented for number of forms. Given for 2 forms only here